# how to display video thumbnail using video url

Tags: android, image, url, video, thumbnails

i have a requirement in my android project To display video thumbnail using video url ,How can i get this can any body give solution for that.the follwoing  code is not working it comes an error

**error:**

:Chunked transfer encoding applied.
   W/NuHTTPDataSource(   34): Server did not give us the content length!

**code:**
   String linkText_url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZ-vxUiOhwc&feature=relmfu";

```
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(linkText_url,  
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);//filePath is your video file path.
    imge.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```